# C# System.Drawing.Image.get_Width() throws exception on WinForms form is maximized

Tags: c#, winforms, fo-dicom

I writing `Windows Forms Application` application which should show image on the `PictureBox` control.

To retrieve this image from `DICOMDIR` file I use [`fo-dicom`](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom) library (driven by [this](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki/Image-rendering) guide):

```
....
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageManager.SetImplementation(WinFormsImageManager.Instance);
}
....

// this function is just for example
// real function is bit complicated
private void ShowImage()
{
    // Getting DICOM file, retrieving all info from it
    // Getting dicomDataset instance
    ....

    var id = dicomDataset.Get<string>(DicomTag.ReferencedFileID, -1);
    var dicomImage = new DicomImage(id);
    var bitmap = dicomImage.RenderImage().AsBitmap();
    pictureBox.Image = bitmap ?? pictureBox.ErrorImage;
}
```

When image is retrieving all works fine. But as soon as I `maximize` my `MainForm`, I got `System.ArgumentException` with `Parameter is not valid` message:

[image: System.ArgumentException]

It looks like this is a .NET Framework bug, but maybe there is a way to fix it by `override`ing `OnPaint()` method of `PictureBox` control?

Have anyone see this bug previously?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. During development this  project I use following software:

1. Windows 10 x64
2. Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition
3. .NET Framework 4.5.1
4. fo-dicom version 3.0.2

**EDIT #1**

The same issue with `Panel` instead of `PictureBox`:

[image: ArgumentException]

Comment: Does it also happen without images? Any code in `Paint` events? `Resize`? `Layout`? When is `ShowImage` called?

Comment: I would not bet too much on being a .Net bug: the framework is not perfect, but it's developed and tested by a strong team. Assume first that you have a bug in your code, and try to fix it instead of workaorund a possible .Net bug.

Comment: The Bitmap class does not generate very good exceptions, "Parameter is not valid" is a it-did-not-work exception.  By far the most common reason is that your program ran out of address space.  Especially likely with DICOM images since they tend to be large.  And the visible bug in the code that you posted, it is extremely important to call Dispose() on bitmap objects you no longer use.  The Image property assignment needs to first dispose the previous bitmap if the property is not null.  And favor Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit", you don't prefer it.

Answer (score 3):

You are facing a known and already fixed bug in fo-dicom 3.0.2. See also https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/634.
For performance reason the Bitmap, that DicomImage.RenderImage().AsBitmap() returns, does not have its own pixel data, but has a pointer to the bytes of DicomImage. So the AsBitmap() does not duplicate all the pixel data in memory.
But if you instanciate the DicomImage in a local variable and save the Bitmap in the control, then the DicomImage is disposed at the end of the method and the pixel data gets garbace collected. The next time, the Bitmap tries to access the pixel data this exception happens.

The next release will have two methods: AsSharedBitmap() - the same as now but more obvious to the user - and AsClonedBitmap().

The workaround now is, to copy the pixel data manually by calling:

var bitmap = dicomImage.RenderImage().AsBitmap()**.Clone()**;