# Fo-dicom code compiling but not executing

Tags: c#, dicom, fo-dicom

I am trying following code to convert a dicom file to jpeg:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing; 
using Dicom.Imaging; 

class RnReadDicom{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        string fileName = "33141578.dcm"; 
        var image = new DicomImage(fileName);
        image.RenderImage().AsSharedBitmap().Save(@"test.jpg");
        }}
```

I am compiling it with following command:

```
$ mcs a.cs -r:Dicom.Core.dll -r:Dicom.Native.dll -r:System.Drawing
```

The code compiles without any error but on running the exe file, it gives following error:

```
$ ./a.exe 

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Dicom.DicomEncoding' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Dicom.IO.IOManager.get_BaseEncoding () [0x00000] in <4b7c269b3e704f3f83dd85bb2721c76a>:0 
  at Dicom.DicomEncoding..cctor () [0x00000] in <4b7c269b3e704f3f83dd85bb2721c76a>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Dicom.Imaging.DicomImage..ctor (System.String fileName, System.Int32 frame) [0x00000] in <4b7c269b3e704f3f83dd85bb2721c76a>:0 
  at RnReadDicom.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <5c119b113a6e4d4b8058662dd31bab14>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Dicom.DicomEncoding' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Dicom.IO.IOManager.get_BaseEncoding () [0x00000] in <4b7c269b3e704f3f83dd85bb2721c76a>:0 
  at Dicom.DicomEncoding..cctor () [0x00000] in <4b7c269b3e704f3f83dd85bb2721c76a>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Dicom.Imaging.DicomImage..ctor (System.String fileName, System.Int32 frame) [0x00000] in <4b7c269b3e704f3f83dd85bb2721c76a>:0 
  at RnReadDicom.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00006] in <5c119b113a6e4d4b8058662dd31bab14>:0
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I am having similar problem with another library for which I have posted [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612313/opendicom-code-compiling-but-not-executing) question. This is using a different library and the error is also different. I suspect answers to these questions will be different hence these are not duplicate question. Moreover, the other question does not have any answer yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenDicom code compiling but not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612313/opendicom-code-compiling-but-not-executing)

Comment: This looks like a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612313/opendicom-code-compiling-but-not-executing so please delete this.

Comment: This is using a different library and the error is different. The question is duplicate if it is solved by same answer. Can you post the answer (to this or other question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the garbage collector destroying the image object. The Bitmap only contains a reference to the pixel data of the image to save space.

This has been described here before: [C# System.Drawing.Image.get_Width() throws exception on WinForms form is maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313402/c-sharp-system-drawing-image-get-width-throws-exception-on-winforms-form-is-ma)

To solve this, use it as this:

```cs
var image = new DicomImage(fileName);
image.RenderImage().AsClonedBitmap().Save(@"test.jpg");
```

By cloning, a real copy of the pixel data is performed.

However, it could be sometimes even trickier: If you e. g. use .NET Core as a starting project and the library, which references fo-dicom uses .NET Standard, you have to add either of these to the start of your program:

```cs
    TranscoderManager.SetImplementation(new MonoTranscoderManager()); // limited codecs, but full .NET Core, runs on Linux. Or:
    TranscoderManager.SetImplementation(new DesktopTranscoderManager()); // loads also native dlls, runs on Windows

    ImageManager.SetImplementation(new RawImageManager()); // if you need .NET Core, you only have byte arrays
    ImageManager.SetImplementation(new WinFormsImageManager()); //if you run Windows and have GDI

    NetworkManager.SetImplementation(new DesktopNetworkManager()); // if you want to run dicom services
```